# winAPI Rotating an Image on Screen while Keeping It Centered and the Background Updated

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing code where a user can pick an image from their computer and rotate it on screen. However, there are two problems that I'm having currently. First, I realized that if the image is rectangular, you can see the old picture before it was rotated behind the new rotated image. Second, when I rotated the image, it seemed to rotate around a certain point on the picture, making the picture go off-screen sometimes. So I wanted to know how I would both keep the old image from showing after I rotated the iamge and also how I would keep the image centered to the screen.

This is my rotate code:

```
int flip = 1;
void rotateImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    Graphics graphic(hdc);
    Image* image = Image::FromFile(filePath);
    int x = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - image->GetWidth()) / 2;
    int y = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - image->GetHeight()) / 2 - 50;
    int xx = image->GetWidth();
    int yy = image->GetHeight();
    if (flip == 1)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate90FlipNone);
    else if (flip == 2)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate180FlipNone);
    else if (flip == 3)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate270FlipNone);

    RECT rc;
    HBRUSH hBr;
    SetRect(&rc, x, y, x + xx, y + yy);
    hBr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBr);

    Status status = graphic.DrawImage(image, x, y);
    RECT updateRect = { 0 };
    updateRect.left = x;
    updateRect.top = y;
    updateRect.right = updateRect.left + image->GetWidth();
    updateRect.bottom = updateRect.top + image->GetHeight();
    flip++;
    if (flip > 4) flip = 1;
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

This part of the code

```
RECT rc;
HBRUSH hBr;
SetRect(&rc, x, y, x + xx, y + yy);
hBr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBr);
```

was me trying to solve the issue of the old image appearing after a rotation, but it seems that it cuts out too much of the window and deletes the controls on the window as well.

Comment: Are you talking about desktop window / wallpaper? Or application window? If it is an application window, call `rotateImage` in `WM_PAINT` message doesn't cover other controls. Could you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample?

Comment: I'm talking about an image on an application window. If so, then how would I setup rotateImage in WM_PAINT so that it is only called when a button is pushed?  WM_PAINT already has things inside. I can give you my full code here: https://pastebin.com/aP4qaCa5

Comment: Your design does not match the usual model for Windows applications. You should do all your drawing to the screen in `WM_PAINT`. When the user clicks the rotate button, the source bitmap should be rotated in memory, and you should mark your window for repainting with `InvalidateRect()`.

Comment: So whenever I click a button, I should set a flag so that the rotate code inside the WM_PAINT runs right?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do the rotation every time you draw? Do it once, when the button is pushed.

Comment: That's why I said I'm going to make a flag for the button rotate inside the WM_PAINT

Comment: @ShadyAF Does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1. Each call to `GdiplusStartup` should be paired with a call to [`GdiplusShutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusshutdown).
2. Compare window width and height with image's.
3. Do drawing work in `WM_PAINT` message
4. Use window client `RECT` instead of screen `RECT` to draw image.
5. Get image width and heigth after rotate the image.

> winAPI Rotating an Image on Screen while Keeping It Centered and the
> Background Updated

The following code piece shows mentioned modifications and can achieve this purpose for me. You can refer to.

```
BOOL fRotate = FALSE;
BOOL fFileOpened = FALSE;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        hr = BufferedPaintInit();
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            // File Menu Exit
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case FILE_OPEN:
            fFileOpened = FALSE;
            OpenFileWindow(hWnd);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            break;
        case PIC_EDIT:
            if (fFileOpened)
            {
                displayDialogW(hWnd);
            }
            else
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Pick an Image File to Edit!", "Error!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
            break;
        case PIC_ROTATE:
            if (fFileOpened)
            {
                fRotate = TRUE;
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            }
            else
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Pick an Image File to Rotate!", "Error!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC screen = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // 3. Do draw work in WM_PAINT message
        if (fRotate)
        {
            rotateImage(hWnd);
            fRotate = FALSE;
        }
        else if (fFileOpened)
        {
            HPAINTBUFFER hbuff = BeginBufferedPaint(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &screen);
            if (hbuff)
            {
                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
                FillRect(screen, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW)); 
                putImage(screen, hWnd);
                hr = EndBufferedPaint(hbuff, TRUE);
            }
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); } break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        BufferedPaintUnInit();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void OpenFileWindow(HWND hWnd)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog* pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
            IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem* pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        char szBuffer[255];
                        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pszFilePath, -1, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), NULL, NULL);
                        // JPG/JPEG/PNG
                        filePath = pszFilePath;
                        fFileOpened = TRUE;
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}

void putImage(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    Graphics graphic(hdc);
    Image* image = Image::FromFile(filePath);

    // 4. Use window client RECT instead of screen RECT to draw image.
    RECT clientRect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);
    LONG cx = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
    LONG cy = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;

    // TODO: 2. compare window width and height with image's before subtract.
    int x = (cx - image->GetWidth()) / 2;
    int y = (cy - image->GetHeight()) / 2;
    Status status = graphic.DrawImage(image, x, y);

#if 1 //For testing purpose and feel free to remove.
    // Draw a line at window middle for checking is the image is centered
    LONG xMid = cx / 2;
    LONG yMid = cy / 2;
    Pen      pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
    graphic.DrawLine(&pen, xMid, 0, xMid, clientRect.bottom);
    graphic.DrawLine(&pen, 0, yMid, clientRect.right, yMid);
#endif // 
}

int flip = 1;
void rotateImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    Graphics graphic(hdc);
    Image* image = Image::FromFile(filePath);

    // 4. Use window client RECT instead of screen RECT to draw image.
    RECT clientRect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);
    LONG cx = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
    LONG cy = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;

    if (flip == 1)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate90FlipNone);
    else if (flip == 2)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate180FlipNone);
    else if (flip == 3)
        image->RotateFlip(Rotate270FlipNone);

    // 5. Get image width and heigth after rotate
    int xx = image->GetWidth();
    int yy = image->GetHeight();

    // TODO: 2. compare window width and height with image's before subtract.
    int x = (cx - xx) / 2;
    int y = (cy - yy) / 2;

    RECT rc;
    HBRUSH hBr;
    SetRect(&rc, x, y, x + xx, y + yy);
    hBr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBr);

    Status status = graphic.DrawImage(image, x, y);
    // Draw a line at window middle
    LONG xMid = cx / 2;
    LONG yMid = cy / 2;
    Pen      pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
    graphic.DrawLine(&pen, xMid, 0, xMid, clientRect.bottom);
    graphic.DrawLine(&pen, 0, yMid, clientRect.right, yMid);

    flip++;
    if (flip > 4) flip = 1;
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

Update: Add result of an image not working for OP.

[image]

Comment: For some pictures, it seems to not center correctly on the window.

Comment: @ShadyAF For those pictures, do their width or height larger than window client area's width or height?

Comment: Nope, it's a small one like this one: https://imgur.com/a/WbnzAHp

Comment: @ShadyAF It is centered for me. Please check the uploaded image in my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird. It looks like this to me: https://imgur.com/a/iHRoacI

Comment: @ShadyAF Have you tried exact my code? What are values of `cx`, `cy`, `x`, `y` and image's width and height for you in `putImage` function?